# How to find which function call on button click in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a button in asp.net web forms. button has click event. i want to know which function call on button click event on runtime.here is an example of code. like we have button

```
<button type='button' id='" + data.d[j]['CustomerId'] + "' onclick='removeCustomer(this)'>Remove</button>
```

I want to know which function call on button click at run time. Like this button call remove customer on click. how i get this function name on runtime.Please guide me.

Comment: to be clear, do you want to know, _which button/control made a post-back request to server_ in **C# (server side code)**? if that is the case, I can help you.

Comment: The mentioned control is a HTML control. There will be no postback when you click it.When there is no postback, no use of writing anything in code behind. If you want to do postback, use server control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have more than one button at your html and you want to determine which of the buttons call removeCustomer function.you can determine this by event target at your javascript :

```
<button type='button' id='" + data.d[j]['CustomerId'] + "' onclick='removeCustomer(this,event)'>Remove</button>
```

at you javascript

```
 function   removeCustomer(elem,e){
    console.log(e.target)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to know what function is being call in onclick event? It's already there: `onclick='removeCustomer(this)'`. Its `removeCustomer`.